# Go to Edit mode of a sharepoint publishing page programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How can I go to edit mode of a sharepoint 2013 publishing page programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by doing a redirect to the page you want to edit appending "?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design" to the URL
(pay attention to the case)

Also the page should be checked out